# How to prove that the zeros of $z^4+iz^3+1$ are in the disk $D(0,\frac{3}{2})$, and determine how many of them are in the first quadrant?

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that the zeros of $z^4+iz^3+1$ are in the disk $D(0,\frac{3}{2})$ and determine how many of them are in the first quadrant.

Comment: :what are you trying ?

Comment: I started arguing about the right half plane: $\alpha=\frac{-\pi}{2}$ and $\beta=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: $s_r:=-it$, $\forall t \in R$

Comment: $p(s_r):=p(-it)=t^4-t^3+1$

Comment: Do you guys think that I do not try?

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'm in exam period :/

Comment: I am tense. And I need help with some exercise.

Comment: @Sophie: In general, people are much more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. So, even if you are stuck, it is best to explain what you understand about the problem, what you don't understand, what you've tried, etc. Also, this way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level.

Comment: ok, thank to all and sorry :(

Comment: @Sophie Germain: hi you couldn't find precisely zeros of $4z^4+iz^3+1$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the circle of radius $R$, $|iz^3+1|\leq R^3+1$ and $|z^4|=R^4$, 
therefore, if $R=3/2$ then $|z^4|>|iz^3+1|$. By Rouché's theorem, the number of zeroes of $z^4$ inside the disc of radius $3/2$ equals the number of zeroes of $z^4+iz^3+1$ in the same disc.
This means that $z^4+iz^3+1$ has all the four roots in the given disc.

For zero in the first quadrant, consider the argument principle: if $Z$ is the number of zeroes of $f$ inside the plane region delimited by the contour $\gamma$, then $\Delta_\gamma(\textrm{arg}f)=2\pi Z$, i.e. the variation of the argument of $f$ along $\gamma$ equals $Z$ times $2\pi$.

Take a path from the origin, following the real axis to the point $M>0$, then make a quarter of circle or radius $M$, reaching the point $iM$ and then go back to the origin along the imaginary axis. Now try to determine the variation of the argument of $f(z)$ along this path for $M\to\infty$:

1. along the real axis, the function is $f(t)=t^4+1 + it^3$, therefore $f(t)$ stays always in the first quadrant for $t\geq0$ (so the total change of argument along this part of the path is between $0$ and $\pi/2$); moreover $f(0)$ has argument equal to $0$ and for $M$ large $\arctan(M^3/M^4+1)=\textrm{arg}f(M)$ is near $0$ again, so the argument stays constant when $M\to\infty$.
2. along the path $Me^{i\theta}$ for $0\leq\theta\leq \pi/2$, if $M$ is very large, the function is near to $g(\theta)=M^4e^{i4\theta}$; therefore the argument goes from $0$ to $2\pi$.
3. along the imaginary axis, the function is real, hence its argument doesn't change.
   So, the total change of the argument is $2\pi$, implying that the function has only one zero in that quadrant.

Comment: I would upvote you for the first part. But I don't follow your argument in the second part. Could you explain more?

Comment: what don't you understand?

Comment: I don't see the problem. It is easier to prove that the zeroes are in the first quadrant considering the whole of it, instead of restricting ourselves to the first quadrant intersected with the disc...

Comment: Sorry, my comment does not make sense, deleted. And I understand, now, +1.

Answer (score 4):

Rouche's theorem on

$$C_{3/2}:=\left\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;|z|=\frac{3}{2}\right\}\;\;\;,\;\;f(z)=z^4\;\;,\;\;g(z)=iz^3+1$$

so

$$z\in C_{3/2}\Longrightarrow |g(z)|\le |z|^3+1=\frac{27}{8}+1<\frac{81}{16}=|f(z)| $$

So $\,f\,\,,\,\,f+g\,\,$ have the same number of zeros within $\,C_{3/2}\,$

Comment: Nicely done, +1.